# Assign texture in texture paint - Cycles render

Tags: texture-painting

This is probably a question with a very simple answer, but I am completely new to blender so I'm not used to the UI. I am making a low-poly landscape from a height map in cycles render and I'm selecting the surfaces I want to give a stone texture. I am following a tutorial but they are using a mac, so I can't find the assign button for the texture.
[image: I'm probably missing something here]

I'm running Blender 2.79b on Windows 10

Comment: Enter Edit mode, select faces which should have stone material and assign that material to faces clicking Assign button (it's present in Edit mode only). It depends on tutorial though, expected result there might be different but OS version shouldn't really matter for Blender UI.

Answer (score 1):

In texture paint, try using the "slots" tab on the toolbar.  Here, you can change painting mode from material to image, then specify a particular image and UV map you'd like to use.

Be aware that this isn't the same thing as assigning a texture to a material for rendering purposes.